# Xcode is constantly hijacking my Editor settings for .rb files

Tags: high-sierra, xcode, ruby, sublimetext

I'm quite baffled by this as i can't find how and why it's happening.
For years i'm using Sublime Text to open ruby files and surely i have Xcode installed but except of command line tools i don't use Xcode as an IDE ever.

Just since today and no software update has been installed in this regard for weeks Xcode registers itself to open .rb files.

When i noticed i used Finder / Get Info and all the normal procedure to fix this.
and this works but only for an hour or so.

Suddenly clicking a ruby file i notice how the file icon changes mid click from the dark grey with orange icon to the white page with red icon from Xcode.

Played this game 5 times today and even tried rebooting.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

[Stop Xcode from Hijacking my File Associations](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316880/stop-xcode-from-hijacking-my-file-associations)

Sounded similar but only so far that for me this happens without any updates just after a short while multiple times a day.

Comment: By chance, do you use Firefox and uBlock Origin?

Comment: Yes using both, why?

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:

> By chance, do you use Firefox and uBlock Origin?
>
> Yes using both, why?

This is due to [a mysterious bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1448374) in Firefox that is triggered by a recent update to uBlock Origin.

[A fix has been applied to uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/issues/3636) to avoid the bug, however that patch has not made it to the latest release yet.

Comment: That's a really odd bug. Nice find! Confirmed your Bug on Bugzilla while i was at it.