# Default apps constantly being reset

Tags: terminal, applications, launchpad

My computer running El Capitan (10.11.6) keeps resetting the apps used to open particular file extensions. For instance, it randomly sets PDFs to open with Acrobat Reader instead of Preview no matter how many times I've used the 'Open with' menu to set the app I want. Strangely, when I right-click and go expand the 'Open with' menu, Preview doesn't even show up in the list – I have to choose other and browse for it.

Possibly related: I've long used the Terminal to launch apps, using `open -a 'name of app'`. That's also stopped working for certain apps. If I for instance try to `open -a 'ia writer classic'` it tells me `Unable to find application named 'ia writer classic'`. If I then launch IA Writer from the Launchpad, close it, and try the command in the Terminal again, it works. At least for a while...

Any clues as to what might be going on would be very helpful!

Comment: First easy thing to try, download 10.11.6 COMBO updater, run it, and see if that fixes anything. If not, reinstall 10.11.6 full installer and see if that fixes things. It sounds like you have some kind of odd software glitch.

Comment: By chance, do you use Firefox and uBlock Origin?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I do, and have been – for longer than I've had this problem, however. Do you think it's related?

Comment: Surprisingly, yes. See: [Xcode is constantly hijacking my Editor settings for .rb files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/320037/xcode-is-constantly-hijacking-my-editor-settings-for-rb-files/320272)